# split lines with a spacing on a canvas rectangle

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw some lines moving away from the bottom edge of a canvas rectangle.

The lines should have the same spacing to each other. This spacing gets calculated by the number of the lines. You can see here what I want to achieve

[image: img]

I started creating this but somehow I don't get the correct line starting position at the bottom side of the big rectangle.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const ctx = $("#c")[0].getContext("2d");

  const mainRect = createRect(ctx, 10, 10, 200, 25);

  const elementCount = 5; // change this value for other results!

  const horizontalPositionModifier = mainRect.width / elementCount;

  for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
    const horizontalPosition = mainRect.start.x + horizontalPositionModifier * i;

    const subRect = createRect(ctx, horizontalPosition, mainRect.start.y + 50, 10, 5);

    drawLine(ctx, horizontalPosition, mainRect.centerBottomPosition.y, subRect.centerBottomPosition.x, subRect.centerBottomPosition.y);
  }
});

function createRect(ctx, startX, startY, width, height) {
  const rect = {
    start: {
      x: startX,
      y: startY
    },
    width: width,
    height: height,
    centerBottomPosition: {
      x: startX + width * 0.5,
      y: startY + height
    }
  };

  drawRect(ctx, rect);

  return rect;
}

function drawRect(ctx, rect) {
  ctx.strokeRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, targetX, targetY) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(targetX, targetY);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
#c {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

---

**EDIT:**

I just modified the lines

```
const horizontalPositionModifier = mainRect.width / elementCount;
```

and

```
const horizontalPosition = mainRect.start.x + horizontalPositionModifier * i;
```

to

```
const horizontalPositionModifier = mainRect.width / (elementCount+1);
```

and

```
const horizontalPosition = mainRect.start.x + horizontalPositionModifier * (i+1);
```

I hope this helps because currently it looks better.

Answer (score 1):

From the image you show, and the code you provide, i believe you require to draw the split line on the middle of the splitted rect.

Try to add in 50% of the length for splitted rect into `horizontalPosition`

```
const horizontalPosition = mainRect.start.x + horizontalPositionModifier * i + (horizontalPositionModifier / 2);
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const ctx = $("#c")[0].getContext("2d");

  const mainRect = createRect(ctx, 10, 10, 200, 25);

  const elementCount = 1; // change this value for other results!

  const horizontalPositionModifier = mainRect.width / elementCount;

  for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
    const horizontalPosition = mainRect.start.x + horizontalPositionModifier * i + (horizontalPositionModifier/2) ;

    const subRect = createRect(ctx, horizontalPosition, mainRect.start.y + 50, 10, 5);

    drawLine(ctx, horizontalPosition, mainRect.centerBottomPosition.y, subRect.centerBottomPosition.x, subRect.centerBottomPosition.y);
  }
});

function createRect(ctx, startX, startY, width, height) {
  const rect = {
    start: {
      x: startX,
      y: startY
    },
    width: width,
    height: height,
    centerBottomPosition: {
      x: startX + width * 0.5,
      y: startY + height
    }
  };

  drawRect(ctx, rect);

  return rect;
}

function drawRect(ctx, rect) {
  ctx.strokeRect(rect.start.x, rect.start.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, targetX, targetY) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(targetX, targetY);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
#c {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Lousy fixes, but it should able to did the job you ask

Comment: no sorry because when I have `5` elements your result from `0` to `100` would be `10, 30, 50, 70, 90` and the correct spacing would be `16, 33, 50, 66, 83`